# How can i get $sum for array in document?

Tags: mongodb, nosql-aggregation

For example, i have following document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52ffddd3c69e40174c046d67"),
    "works" : [ 
        {
            "service_id" : ObjectId("52ffd576c69e40174c046d64"),
            "price" : 150,
            "count" : 3,
            "items" : [ 
                {
                    "price" : 5,
                    "amount" : 10
                }, 
                {
                    "price" : 7,
                    "amount" : 3
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "service_id" : ObjectId("52ffd56fc69e40174c046d63"),
            "price" : 100,
            "count" : 2
        }
    ]
}
```

Where service_id refers to some outer document (i know, it's not recommended), price is price for work, count is how many times work have been performed, and items is array for materials, used in **all** works.
I need to get total price for all works. I tried following unfinished code:

```
db.service_cards.aggregate(
    { $match: {_id: ObjectId("52ffddd3c69e40174c046d67") } },
    { $unwind: "$works" },
    { $project: {
        "works.service_id": 1,
        "works.price": 1,
        "works.count": 1,
        "works.items": { 
            "$cond": [ 
                { $eq: [ "$works.items", []] },
                [{
                    "price": 0,
                    "amount": 0
                }],
                "$works.items"
            ],
        }
    } },
    { $project: {
        "works.service_id": 1,
        "works.price": 1,
        "works.count": 1,
        "works.items": { 
            "$ifNull": [ 
                "$works.items",
                [{
                    "price": 0,
                    "amount": 0
                }]
            ],
        }
    } },
    { $unwind: "$works.items" },
    { $project: { 
        "service_id": "$works.service_id",
        "price": "$works.price",
        "count": "$works.count",
        "items_cost": { $multiply: ["$works.items.price", "$works.items.amount"] },
    } },
    { $group: { 
        _id: "$service_id", 
        "sum_items": { $sum: "$items_cost" },
        "price": { $avg: "$price" },
        "count": { $avg: "$count" }
    } }
)
```

It doesn't actually sum arrays - it unwinds works and items, then uses $group to sum unwinded items. But then i remembered - there could be two works with equal service_id, count and price, and after $unwind and $group, i'll lose one of them, putting items from both together.

Is there any way to get array $sum inside document without $unwind?

**Edit:**
I expect to receive a list of works without their items, but with total items cost:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52ffddd3c69e40174c046d67"),
    "works" : [ 
        {
            "service_id" : ObjectId("52ffd576c69e40174c046d64"),
            "price" : 150,
            "count" : 3,
            "items_cost" : 71
        }, 
        {
            "service_id" : ObjectId("52ffd56fc69e40174c046d63"),
            "price" : 100,
            "count" : 2,
            "items_cost": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: The short answer is no. The long answer depends on what do you **expect** to do and receive as a result document. Which as yet remains unclear in your question. Perhaps if you added what you want and expect, then people can help with your problem. By Add we mean, edit your question to include that and make things clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, it is not better solution, but it is short and doing what you want:

```
db.service_cards.find().forEach(function (document) {
    var works = document.works || [];
    var result = [];
    works.forEach(function (work) {
        var items = work.items || [];
        var itemsCost = 0;
        items.forEach(function (item) {
            itemsCost += item.price * item.amount;
        });
        var resultObj = {
            service_id: work.service_id,
            price: work.price,
            count: work.count,
            items_cost: itemsCost
        };
        result.push(resultObj);
    });
    print({
        _id: document._id,
        works: result
    });
})
```